# Python: LightGBM Hyperparameter Tuning Value Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification, lightgbm

I have written the following code to perform `RandomizedSearchCV` on LightGBM Classifier Model, but I am getting the following error.

`ValueError: For early stopping, at least one dataset and eval metric is required for evaluation`

**Code**

```
import lightgbm as lgb
fit_params={"early_stopping_rounds":30, 
            "eval_metric" : 'f1', 
            "eval_set" : [(X_val,y_val)],
            'eval_names': ['valid'],
            'verbose': 100,
            # 'categorical_feature': 'auto'
            }

from scipy.stats import randint as sp_randint
from scipy.stats import uniform as sp_uniform
param_test ={'num_leaves': sp_randint(6, 50), 
             'min_child_samples': sp_randint(100, 500), 
             'min_child_weight': [1e-5, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3, 1e4],
             'subsample': sp_uniform(loc=0.2, scale=0.8), 
             'colsample_bytree': sp_uniform(loc=0.4, scale=0.6),
             'reg_alpha': [0, 1e-1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 50, 100],
             'reg_lambda': [0, 1e-1, 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]}

n_HP_points_to_test = 100

from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
#n_estimators is set to a "large value". The actual number of trees build will depend on early stopping and 5000 define only the absolute maximum
clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier(max_depth=-1, 
                         random_state=42, 
                         silent=True, 
                         metric='f1', 
                         n_jobs=4, 
                         n_estimators=5000,
                         )

gs = RandomizedSearchCV(
    estimator=clf, param_distributions=param_test, 
    n_iter=n_HP_points_to_test,
    scoring='f1',
    cv=3,
    refit=True,
    random_state=41,
    verbose=True)

gs.fit(X_trn, y_trn, **fit_params)
print('Best score reached: {} with params: {} '.format(gs.best_score_, gs.best_params_))
```

**Tried Solutions**
I have tried to implement the solutions given in the following links, but none of them worked. How to fix this?

1. [LightGBM error : ValueError: For early stopping, at least one dataset and eval metric is required for evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61694081/lightgbm-error-valueerror-for-early-stopping-at-least-one-dataset-and-eval-m)
2. [ValueError: For early stopping, at least one dataset and eval metric is required for evaluation #3028](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/3028)
3. [For early stopping, at least one dataset and eval metric is required for evaluation #1597](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1597)

Answer (score 1):

The `F1` is not in built-in metric in LightGBM. You can easily add a custom eval_metric:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

def lightgbm_eval_metric_f1(preds, dtrain):
    target = dtrain.get_label()
    weight = dtrain.get_weight()

    unique_targets = np.unique(target)
    if len(unique_targets) > 2:
        cols = len(unique_targets)
        rows = int(preds.shape[0] / len(unique_targets))
        preds = np.reshape(preds, (rows, cols), order="F")

    return "f1", f1_score(target, preds, weight), True
```

Regarding optimization, I rather use native python API for LightGBM (`lightgbm.train`) with the `Optuna` framework, which works really well.

Optuna framework: https://github.com/optuna/optuna

But the easiest way to tune LightGBM with Optuna will be to use MLJAR AutoML (it has `f1` metric built-in).

```py
automl = AutoML(
    mode="Optuna"
    algorithms=["LightGBM"],
    optuna_time_budget=600, # 10 minutes for tuning 
    eval_metric="f1"
)
automl.fit(X, y)
```

MLJAR AutoML framework: https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised

If you want to check details of LightGBM+Optuna optimization in MLJAR here is the code https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised/blob/master/supervised/tuner/optuna/lightgbm.py

Answer (score 0):

The last message in your third link (Feb 2020) suggests this error gets raised if the metric is not recognized, and indeed `"f1"` is not one of [LGBM's builtin metrics](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#metric-parameters).  Either use one of their builtins (but you can still use F1 as the hyperparameter search's selection criterion), or create a custom metric (see the note at the end of the [`LGBMClassifier.fit` method's documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.fit)).